Stompjs + React application - Client connection closed automatically
I'm trying to use the stompjs library along with React application to establish a WebSocket connection with a server. However, I'm facing an issue where the connection is opened and closed immediately.
connection closed message on debug
connection closed message on debug
I create my protocol configuration code in a file stomp.ts:
import { Client, StompConfig } from '@stomp/stompjs'
import SocksJS from 'sockjs-client'

const ROOT_API = 'https://api.staging.x.com'
const AUTH_TOKEN ='x'
const ATTENDANT_ID = 752

const stompConfig: StompConfig = {
  connectHeaders: {},
  brokerURL: ROOT_API,
  webSocketFactory: () => new SocksJS(`${ROOT_API}/secured/attendance?Authorization=${AUTH_TOKEN}`),
  forceBinaryWSFrames: false,
  appendMissingNULLonIncomin: true,
  heartbeatOutgoing: 4000,
  heartbeatIncoming: 4000,
  debug: (str) => {
    console.log('STOMP', str)
  },
  reconnectDelay: 5000,
  onConnect: () => {
    console.log('connected')
    stompClient.subscribe(
      `/secured/attendance/messages.${ATTENDANT_ID}`,
      (message) => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(message.body))
       
      },
    )
    stompClient.publish({
      destination: '/sgm/secured/attendance/configure',
      body: undefined,
    })
  },
}

const stompClient = new Client(stompConfig)

export { stompClient }

After a haver my App.tsx file
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { stompClient  } from "./stomp"

export function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    stompClient.activate()
  }, [])

  return (
    <strong>Hello world</strong>
  )
}



